# Preventing Chrome from signing me out from Gmail when browsing in icognito

Tags: iphone, ios, google-chrome, gmail

When using Google Chrome in incognito mode on iOS on iPhone, it signs me out from Gmail after one or tow hours: how can I prevent it?

Comment: Incognito mode is not meant for authenticated services such as Gmail. It's meant to help prevent tracking, such as when viewing news sites and whatever.

Comment: @efr4k on desktop it doesn't disconnect unless one closes all incognito windows.

Comment: Yes, but it is not the intended use for incognito mode still. Therefore you cannot expect that to continue to work, and might be the reason why you experience different results on mobile vs desktop. I just tested, if you open a new incognito window instead of tab your cookies from the other window is not present.

Answer (score 3):

If I'm correct, using incognito mode means it doesn't save cookies or other caching method to keep you signed in on your device.

Comment: Correct, but that that doesn't mean Google Chrome should automatically sign off the user. Instead, it could wait for the user to close all incognito windows to do so, as it does on desktop.

Comment: Good to know this helps. Please be so kind to mark my answer as correct so others know this is the correct answer.